# Why the centos curl version is different with php curl version

Tags: php, curl, centos

I updated centos7 curl and now the version is 7.65, then I rebuilt php7 and `set --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl`. When I finished `curl_version()` still shows 7.20. Why is that?

I use guzzle to request a web which need http_version 2.0, so I have to upgrade php curl. Hope someone helps me, thanks a lot!

Comment: For future people experiencing this problem: after `sudo reboot` my curl version matched up with my libcurl version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update libcurl and use the installation path as compile option `--with-curl=/path/to/libcurl`

To do so follow the next steps:

As described [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using):

1. install curl-config
2. find the path of libcurl with `curl-config --cflags`
3. use `curl-config --version` to determine the libcurl version
4. if it is not the version you expect, rebuild curl with the `--includedir` option
5. rebuild php with the option `--with-curl=/path/to/libcurl`

Comment: The curl -V command  show me my libcurl version is 7.65 like this: libcurl/7.65.0

Comment: The path in your option should point to the location of your libcurl, not to the binary.

Comment: I set --with-curl=/usr/local/lib ,but it doesn't work，i found /usr/lib64 and /usr/local/lib also has libcurl.so、libcurl.so.4、libcurl.so.4.2.0，i have no idea and crazy，how do i sure the libcurl is correct???

Comment: Follow this steps https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using/ to get the version and location of your libcurl

Comment: Hi i found the solution way，first step use curl-config --cflags to find which path the libcurl , second step use curl-config --version to make sure the curl version , it really show me libcurl 7.20, last step i rebuilt curl-7.65 and add --includedir options, after make it works, php show me the curl version is 7.65, HAHAHAHA, thanks so so so so so so much!!!!!!

Comment: glad to helped you